# Javascript wont run when include tags are echoed to <head> - PHP, JS, HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hey, I just made a simple function to load JavaScript files from a template view, like this:

```
public function includeJavascript($file){   
        if(file_exists('path/to/js/' . $file)){
            $this->set('script', '<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/js/' . $file . '"></script>');
        }
    }
```

The string is passed via $script and gets printed in the main layout. This means that when I render the page I actually get: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/js/myjavascript.js'"></script>` in the HTML, but the JavaScript code wont run. Why is this?

Sincerely, Why

Comment: `file_exists(path/to/js/' . $file)` should be `file_exists('path/to/js/' . $file)`

Comment: Further, `... src="/path/to/js/myjavascript.js'">` has an extra `'`

Comment: Have you checked to see whether the HTTP transaction to fetch the script actually worked?

Comment: Since he is getting the script tag in his html we can assume that both of those errors mentioned above are just typos in his question.
@why - how do you know that the js isn't running?  Test 1, take the content of the script "src" tag, copy to your URL bar and see if the script appears in your browser window.

Comment: Yes, the file is accessible from firebug. You are right James, they are just typos. I apologize guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily add this line to the top of myjavascript.js as a sanity check..

```
alert('found myjavascript.js OK!');
```

Comment: The alert shows up! Could the problem be something specific to GeoSuggester?

Comment: All you have done is satisfy yourself that at least this particular script has been found.  Now, did it get found before a particular event was fired? or did it get called correctly? These are different JS debugging issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function includeJavascript($file){   
        if(file_exists('path/to/js/' . $file)){
            $this->set('script', '<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/js/' . $file . '"></script>');
        }
    }
```

Addded an apostrophe prior to `path/to/js/` in the `file_exists` function.

If you look at the code you posted in the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/js/myjavascript.js'"></script>
```

Note the extra apostrophe after `myjavascript.js`? That's why it won't work.